# How do I disable sending traceback to remote hosts?

Tags: python, security, twisted, traceback, twisted.web

How can I keep Twisted from sending traceback to the browser when it has an error? It's been exposing file paths and code.

[image]

Comment: Don't run a production application in debug mode or whatever it's called with twisted.

Comment: To reinterpret @ThiefMaster's comment, the solution is to disable debug mode or whatever it's called!

Comment: To reinterpret @mhlester, there's maybe this thing called debug mode or something, and you should turn it off or whatever!

Comment: More formally, @CodyPiersall says: the attribute set M of modes contains an element that is semantically equivalent to "debug". Ensure that the value of this attribute is semantically equivalent to "False"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just about every server framework that serves up something human readable will have an option to serve up tracebacks (for development) or not (for production).

In Twisted, it's called `displayTracebacks`, and it's documented as a member of [`twisted.web.server.Site`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.web.server.Site.html). You configure it the same way(s) you configure anything else in Twisted. (The corresponding one-word option, e.g., for command-line flags, is `notracebacks`.)

If you're wondering why it defaults to True, you may want to read Glyph's rationale on the [2003 feature request that added this flag in the first place](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/135):

> Nope, this should be turned on by default, since when you
>   are using defaults you are typically developing.  System
>   administrators can make this a site-local default by adding
>   to sitecustomize.py or somesuch.

(As the 11-years-wiser version of Glyph points out in a comment, it's probably better to set it in the application than to use a site-local default. But the basic idea is the same. Set it to `False` at any level, and you'll get exactly the behavior you're after.)

Comment: Can I make it output traceback to `stdout` but not in an HTTP reply?

Comment: @AustinBurk: I don't think there's any way to specifically output tracebacks to `stdout`, but by default they already go to wherever your logging is configured to go. (Have you read the basic tutorials on logging and configuration in Twisted?)

Comment: I'm logging everything already. It outputs to a log file now, but if you try to go to it in a browser it'll show traceback. :|

Comment: @AustinBurk: So right now, it's in the logs and in the output page. If you disable `displayTracebacks`, it'll be in the logs and nowhere else. Is that what you want?

Comment: Don't actually make it "site-local", just set it in your application :-).

Comment: @Glyph: Yes, what was that Glyph guy thinking? Good thing Glyph is around to correct him. :)

Comment: The internet permanently archives all of our mistakes equally.  Best never to say anything ;-)